# Access data external network with Javascript Yammer API

Tags: javascript, yammer

I'm able to retrieve yammer groups when I log in to my default **home** network. From the moment that I switch to an **external** network, it can't retrieve the yammer groups.

response.authResponse is false in that case.

It's probably a token issue. Who can provide me a code snippet to handle this issue?

## JavaScript API Snippet

```
yam.platform.getLoginStatus(
function (response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
      onLoginSuccess();
  }
  else {
    onLoginFailure();
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more detail (code) on the issue you're having.

Answer (score 1):

a session token must be obtained for the external network, this answer shows the js snippet:

[how-to-get-access-tokens-of-users-in-external-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25903804/how-to-get-access-tokens-of-users-in-external-network/26311522#26311522)