# How to get access tokens of users in external network?

Tags: yammer

I have a admin account, first I got access tokens for each network the admin account is a member.
second I used the `user_id` and `consumer_key` parameters to generate tokens on behalf of other users.
But when I try to get access token of user in external network,I got a `401` error. There is no problem to get access token of user in main network.I want to know is there any way to get access tokens of users in external networks.

Answer (score 1):

The **network parameter** is the key in the puzzle when invoking the login method.
Due to some cross domain restrictions, the SDK creates a hidden iframe on the page to serve as a proxy bridge to get a token for the external network.

```
yam.platform.login({ network: '{your-permalink-goes-here}' }, function (data) {

    console.log('login-status: ',data)
    if(data.status ==='connected')
        yam.platform.request({
            url: "oauth/tokens.json"     
            , method: "GET"
            , success: function (tokens) { console.log('user-tokens:',tokens); }
            , error: function (err) { alert("There was an error with the request."); }
        });
})
```

The obtained token can be then manually set for further requests whenever the page is reloaded, avoiding the login window to show up again.

```
yam.platform.setAuthToken('{the-token-goes-here}'))
```